# Sending Data from Hono to Ditto ( amqp:resource-limit-exceeded)

Tags: eclipse-hono, eclipse-ditto

Hono and Ditto are successfully connected. But when I try to send the data from Hono, I will be getting 503 - Service not available message.

But then when I checked the Ditto logs. I got the below AMQP Limit exceeded.

```
connectivity_1   | 2019-10-14 16:34:38,294 INFO  [] o.e.d.s.c.m.ConnectionActor akka://ditto- 
cluster/system/sharding/connection/6/hono-sandbox-connection-123/pa - Starting ClientActor for 
connection <hono-sandbox-connection-123> with <1> clients.
connectivity_1   | 2019-10-14 16:34:38,308 INFO  [] a.a.RepointableActorRef akka://ditto- 
cluster/system/distributedPubSubMediator - Message 
[org.eclipse.ditto.signals.events.connectivity.ConnectionCreated] from Actor[akka://ditto- 
cluster/system/sharding/connection/6/hono-sandbox-connection-123/pa#233633004] to Actor[akka://ditto- 
cluster/system/distributedPubSubMediator#-301178072] was not delivered. [9] dead letters encountered. 
If this is not an expected behavior, then [Actor[akka://ditto- 
cluster/system/distributedPubSubMediator#-301178072]] may have terminated unexpectedly, This logging 
can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead- 
letters-during-shutdown'.
connectivity_1   | 2019-10-14 16:34:38,441 INFO  [] o.a.q.j.s.SaslMechanismFinder  - Best match for 
SASL auth was: SASL-PLAIN
connectivity_1   | 2019-10-14 16:34:38,721 INFO  [] o.a.q.j.s.SaslMechanismFinder  - Best match for 
SASL auth was: SASL-PLAIN
connectivity_1   | 2019-10-14 16:34:39,128 INFO  [] o.a.q.j.s.SaslMechanismFinder  - Best match for 
SASL auth was: SASL-PLAIN
connectivity_1   | 2019-10-14 16:34:39,781 INFO  [] o.a.q.j.s.SaslMechanismFinder  - Best match for 
SASL auth was: SASL-PLAIN
connectivity_1   | 2019-10-14 16:34:40,962 INFO  [] o.a.q.j.s.SaslMechanismFinder  - Best match for 
SASL auth was: SASL-PLAIN
connectivity_1   | 2019-10-14 16:34:41,020 WARN  [] o.e.d.s.c.m.a.JMSConnectionHandlingActor 
akka://ditto-cluster/system/sharding/connection/6/hono-sandbox-connection- 
123/pa/$a/c1/jmsConnectionHandling-hono-sandbox-connection-123-connect1 - Failed to connect JMS 
client:connection disallowed by local policy [condition = amqp:resource-limit-exceeded]
```

I am not sure what does AMQP:Resource limit exceeded error mean? Is this preventing me to send from Hono to Ditto?

Will it work if I drop all these below dbs in the Ditto Mongo server and create new things and Connections again?.

```
> show dbs
admin         0.000GB
concierge     0.000GB
config        0.000GB
connectivity  0.000GB
local         0.000GB
policies      0.002GB
searchDB      0.001GB
things        0.337GB
```

Edit :I tried to connect Eclipse Hono and Eclipse Ditto again in the same servers where I am getting errors.

I got status 201 (connection created) message when I executed the curl commnad. But when I checked my log at the same time, I got the following message.

```
connectivity_1_ad306c4c315b | 2019-10-15T15:46:36.233449988Z 2019-10-15 17:46:36,233 WARN  [] o.e.d.s.c.m.ConnectionActor akka://ditto-cluster/system/sharding/connection/12/test_co_nn_id_12/pa - Operation <connect> on connection <test_co_nn_id_12> failed due to ConnectionFailedException: Failed to connect JMS client:connection disallowed by local policy [condition = amqp:resource-limit-exceeded].
```

**Note :** It is working completely fine when I am trying this in my local machine or in different server.

Comment: The name of the connection in the log (hono-sandbox-connection-123) makes me wonder if you are trying to connect your Ditto instance to Hono's hosted sandbox instance (hono.eclipse.org)? Or are you running and using your own Hono instance? Apart from that, the error regarding the "connection disallowed by local policy" usually means that Ditto is using incorrect credentials for connecting to Hono.

Comment: I tried with multiple connection ids. And I got the same error. Please let me know what is amqp resource limit exceeded ?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion on incorrect suggestions. But when I used the Curl command to connect Hono and Ditto. I got the status as 201(Connection created). But when I try to send the Data from Hono after successful connection. I am getting 503 Service Unavailable message.

Comment: "I got status 201 (connection created) message when I executed the curl commnad."
What Curl command are you executing? And against which endpoint, Hono or Ditto?

Answer (score 1):

I removed the stack and cleared the MongoDB completely using

```
docker-compose down
```

Then reinstalled Ditto. Made Hono and Ditto connections and tried to send data as earlier. Everything worked as expected.